# Automatic Piecewise Approximation

Tags: function-construction, fitting, piecewise

I would like to create the following function:
It should approximate a function `func[x]` by piecewise polynomial interpolations, splitting the approximate function in `n` different polynomials, from `xMin` to `xMax`.

```
autoPiecewiseApproximation[func[x],{xMin,xMax,n}]
```

Example: the square root function

For instance for two subdivisons `n = 2` and `xMin = 0`, `xMax = 1`, the function would automatically generate this:

```
m = Piecewise[{{Fit[
     Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 0.5, .01}], {1, x, x^2, E^x}, x] , 
    0 <= x <= 0.5}, {Fit[
     Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0.5, 1, .01}], {1, x, x^2, E^x}, x] , 
    0.5 < x <= 1}}]
```

Anyone knows how to do this correctly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pW[f_, n_, m_, min_: 0, max_: 1] := Piecewise[
  {Fit[Table[{x, f @ x}, {x, ##, (#2 - #)/m}], {1, x, x^2, E^x}, x], # < x <= #2} & @@@
   Partition[Subdivide[min, max, n], 2, 1]]
```

Examples:

```
pW[Sqrt, 4, 10] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{cases}
>  -149.176 x^2-246.803 x+251.787 e^x-251.768 & 0<x\leq \frac{1}{4} \\
>  -2.882 x^2-1.65139 x+3.18162 e^x-2.99226 & \frac{1}{4}<x\leq \frac{1}{2}
>    \\
>  -0.876557 x^2+0.489058 x+0.663232 e^x-0.41176 & \frac{1}{2}<x\leq
>    \frac{3}{4} \\
>  -0.418328 x^2+0.738036 x+0.220335 e^x+0.0813601 & \frac{3}{4}<x\leq 1
> \end{cases}$

```
pW[Sqrt, 5, 50, 5, 15] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{cases}
>  -0.010714 x^2+0.328728 x+\text{9.866783884779016$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6} e^x+0.858866 & 5<x\leq 7 \\
>  -0.00658734 x^2+0.280252 x+\text{6.475622629784991$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7} e^x+1.00608 & 7<x\leq 9 \\
>  -0.00455749 x^2+0.248165 x+\text{5.00746734942773$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} e^x+1.13528 & 9<x\leq 11 \\
>  -0.00338884 x^2+0.224974 x+\text{4.292376170350944$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9} e^x+1.25171 & 11<x\leq 13 \\
>  -0.00264528 x^2+0.207225 x+\text{3.949544062291019$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10} e^x+1.3585 & 13<x\leq 15
> \end{cases}$

Comment: This is great ! Thanks a lot ! Can you just explain me what n and m is used for ? Is there any way to also include the function (like  Sqrt) as an input to pW[] ?

Comment: @james, `n` is the number of pieces the domain $[min,max]$ is divided into. `m` is the number of points used for `Fit`ting for each piece. You can make the function to approximated an argument using `pW[f_,n_,m_,min_:0,max_:1] := ...` and replacing `Sqrt`  with `f` on the right-hand-side of the definition.